# Obtener fecha completa con laravel en español

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

necesito si me pueden ayudar con esto, necesito obtener la fecha en español con laravel y carbon.  Por ejemplo, necesito obtener la fecha de la siguiente manera `Jueves 04 de junio del 2020`, por el momento obtengo la fecha pero en ingles

```
$diaActual = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
echo {{$now->format('l d \d\e F \d\e\l Y')}}
```

lo cual me trae de vuelta `Thursday 04 de June del 2020`

Estuve viendo mi **config/app** y mi  **Application Locale Configuration** esta  `'locale' => 'es',` no entiendo por que no puedo verlo en español.

Dentro de mi codigo le agrege esta linea

```
**setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');**
$diaActual = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
echo {{$now->format('l d \d\e F \d\e\l Y')}}
```

Pero tampoco toma la fecha en español, que estoy haciendo mal, o existe otra forma de ver la fecha como la necesito

Gracias

Comment: porloscerros gracias, he probado, pero me sigue arrojando la fecha como la necesito en ingles :'(

Comment: También así `Carbon::now()->locale('es')->isoFormat('dddd\, D \d\e MMMM \d\e\l Y')`, más parecido a lo que estabas haciendo, aunque el resultado es similar.

Comment: Muchas gracais amigoa, me ha funcionado con tu ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `->isoFormat(string $formato)`:

> La cadena usa el formato ISO en lugar del formato específico de PHP y usa traducciones internas en lugar de los paquetes de idiomas que necesita instalar en cada máquina donde implementa su aplicación.

Entonces si en tu aplicación tienes configurado `'locale' => 'es'` en el archivo `/config/app.php`, puedes directamente hacer:

```
$diaActual = Carbon::now()->isoFormat('dddd D \d\e MMMM \d\e\l Y');
// jueves 4 de junio del 2020
```

O puedes usar la localización de Carbon para aplicarlo solo a la instacia actual (no necesitarás tener la localización de toda la aplicación en `'es'`):

```
$diaActual = Carbon::now()->locale('es')->isoFormat('dddd D \d\e MMMM \d\e\l Y');
// jueves 4 de junio del 2020
```

---

O si prefieres el patrón de PHP `date()`, puedes usar `->translatedFormat(string $formato)` que funciona como `format()` pero traduce la cadena usando la configuración regional actual.

Entonces si en tu aplicación tienes configurado `'locale' => 'es'`, puedes directamente hacer:

```
$diaActual = Carbon::now()->translatedFormat('l d \d\e F \d\e\l Y');
// jueves 04 de junio del 2020
```

O solo en la instacia actual:

```
$diaActual = Carbon::now()->locale('es')->translatedFormat('l d \d\e F \d\e\l Y');
// jueves 04 de junio del 2020
```

---

**Referencias**:

Carbon [Localization](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo