# ¿Cómo formatear a español las fechas en el Blade? Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

bien, el asunto es el siguiente.

tengo unas fechas que están guardadas en la `BDD` y las muestro en una tabla, el inconveniente es que el formato que me muestra es `2020-01-21` pero necesito que sean del siguiente formato `21 Enero 2020` y lo que conseguí fue `21 January 2020` osea tengo lo que quiero pero lo necesito en español.

como lo muestro, pues así:

```
<table>
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          @foreach ($datos_ar as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$item->item_ar}}</td>
                <td>{{date("d F Y", strtotime($item->fecha_ar))}}<td>
                <td>botones</td>
             </tr>
          @endforeach
      </tbody>
</table>
```

espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!

Comment: En tu proyecto ve a config, luego a app.php y ahí busca en el array asociativo la clave que hace referencia al lenguaje y cambia ese valor a spanish me parece

Comment: @BetaM, eso ya lo tenia hecho desde el inicio.

Comment: Ok, entonces dame oportunidad y te planteo alguna otra forma

Comment: @BetaM claro amigo, gracias!

Comment: Tal vez esto puede ayudar: [Obtener fecha en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200149/obtener-nombre-de-mes-en-espa%C3%B1ol-laravel-carbon)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Obtener nombre de mes en Español (Laravel, Carbon)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200149/obtener-nombre-de-mes-en-espa%c3%b1ol-laravel-carbon)

Comment: yo no fui quien preguntó @FabianM

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Obtener fecha completa con laravel en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/362307/obtener-fecha-completa-con-laravel-en-espa%c3%b1ol)

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, tenía el mismo problema, pero lo acabo de probar y funciona bien. En el controlador desde donde accedo a la vista hago:

```
  public function panel()
  {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
    return view('admin.user.panel');
  }
```

Luego para tu caso en la vista sería:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse(strtotime($item->fecha_ar))->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y') }}
```

Comment: una pregunta donde exactamente coloco el setlocale, dices en el controlador pero que dentro de la función o donde, nunca lo habia hecho antes, gracias!

Comment: Ahí lo edite, simplificado para dejar lo que te importa, antes de hacer el return a la vista agregás el setlocale

Comment: me sigue dando la fecha en ingles, yo pensaba que era en otro lado por eso pregunte, pero lo tenia bien colocado.

Comment: Tal vez sea algún conflicto con el strtotime, en mi caso el campo ya es tipo date por lo que no necesito hacer esa transformación.

Comment: mi campo también es tipo date.

Comment: `{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse(strtotime($item->fecha_ar))->diffForHumans()}} ` utilizando ese metodo `diffForHumans()` es el único que traduce el resto sigue en ingles, pero ese no es el que necesito :/

Comment: strtotime tranforma un string en datetime, si el campo es date no necesitas hacerlo

Comment: Men, funcionaria con lo que tu dices pero, en mi caso funciono con `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` y existe otro problema que es cuando quiero poner días ej: `miércoles 01 junio 2020` no me muestra nada por la tilde entonces tengo que usar `Carbon::setUTF8(true);` y con eso funcionaria. ahora el asunto es que par hacer eso en varios controladores mejor lo pongo en `AppServiceProvider ` en la función boot() y ya solo lo "configuro" en el .blade

Answer (score 1):

En tu `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` agrega en la funcion boot `\Carbon::setLocate(config('app.locale'))` tu app localmente debe estar en `es`, esto lo vez en el archivo `config/app.php.`

Otra opcion que puedes usar es cambiar las instancias de Carbon a Español con el paquete

https://github.com/Jenssegers/Date

Comment: eso ya lo tenia, pero me seguía mandando en ingles, me fui a buscar en otras paginas y me recomendaron usar en `AppServiceProvider` en la funcion boot  `setlocale(LC_TIME, "");` y con eso funciono.